# Como repetir um trecho de html usando laço de repetição em php?

Tags: php, html, loop

```
 <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action='enviaMform.php'>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nomeHost">Host que pretende monitorar:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeHost">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ipHost">Ip do host:</label>
            <input type="text" max="12" name="ipHost" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sistemaOperacional">Sistema operacional:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sistemaOperacional">    
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="marcaModelo">Serviço hospedado no host:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="servicoHospedado">    
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="marcaModelo">Marca e modelo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marcaModelo">    
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="tpMonitoramento">Tipo de monitoramento:</label>   
         <div class="form-control">
             <input type="checkbox" value="Simples" name="tpMonitoramento[]" /> <label for="simples">Simples</label>
         </div><br>
         <div class="form-control">
             <input type="checkbox" value="ZabbixAgent" name="tpMonitoramento[]" /> <label for="Zabbix Agent">Zabbix Agent</label>
         </div> <br>
         <div class="form-control">
             <input type="checkbox" value="MonitoramentoWeb" name="tpMonitoramento[]" /> <label for="simples">Monitoramento Web</label>
         </div><br>
         <div class="form-control">
             <input type="checkbox" value="MonitoramentoODBC" name="tpMonitoramento[]" /> <label for="simples">Monitoramento ODBC</label>
         </div> <br> 
         <button class="btn-block">Deseja monitorar mais algum host?</button>
         <br>
        <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-info btn-block" style="color: #2196F3;"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Tenho essa div enorme e gostaria que quando o usuário clicasse em "Deseja monitorar mais algum host?",fosse possível repeti-la,mas não faço idéia de como fazer isso.

Comment: você deseja repetir este mesmo bloco de código?

Comment: o seu submit do form é tratado antes de ser executado? pois caso aconteça o refresh da página o conteúdo vai se perder

Comment: Sim,desejo repeti-lo

Comment: No caso,tenho uma função de cadastro na página do action que salva esses dados no banco

Comment: Tô considerando mandar o usuario de volta pra essa página por meio de um link de redirecionamento após salvar os dados no banco,mas queria saber se há alguma maneira otimizada de fazer isso na mesma página,sem obrigá-lo a toda vez que deseja fazer um novo registro repetir o processo de salvar e voltar

Comment: via javascript, pode usar ajax pra salvar os dados, e manipular o DOM via javascript.

Comment: algo assim? https://codepen.io/alvaro-alves/pen/zJzpMG?editors=1011

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Comment: O resto da manipulação dos dados eu posso fazer posteriormente,mas ainda assim,obrigadissimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar de não ser um approach muito bom, você pode fazer desta forma e enviar os dados para salvar via ajax:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container" id="Corpo">
  <div id="principal">
        <form method="POST" action='enviaMform.php'>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nomeHost">Host que pretende monitorar:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeHost">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ipHost">Ip do host:</label>
            <input type="text" max="12" name="ipHost" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sistemaOperacional">Sistema operacional:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sistemaOperacional">    
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="marcaModelo">Serviço hospedado no host:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="servicoHospedado">    
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="marcaModelo">Marca e modelo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marcaModelo">    
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="tpMonitoramento">Tipo de monitoramento:</label>   
         <div class="form-control">
             <input type="checkbox" value="Simples" name="tpMonitoramento[]" /> <label for="simples">Simples</label>
         </div><br>
         <div class="form-control">
             <input type="checkbox" value="ZabbixAgent" name="tpMonitoramento[]" /> <label for="Zabbix Agent">Zabbix Agent</label>
         </div> <br>
         <div class="form-control">
             <input type="checkbox" value="MonitoramentoWeb" name="tpMonitoramento[]" /> <label for="simples">Monitoramento Web</label>
         </div><br>
         <div class="form-control">
             <input type="checkbox" value="MonitoramentoODBC" name="tpMonitoramento[]" /> <label for="simples">Monitoramento ODBC</label>
         </div> <br> 
         <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="copyBlock()">Deseja monitorar mais algum host?</a>
         <br>
        <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-info btn-block" style="color: #2196F3;"/>
        </div>
    </form>
          </div>
    </div>
  </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
function copyBlock(){
var secao = document.createElement("div");
            secao.setAttribute("class", "col-xs-12 col-sm-12");
            var formGroup = document.createElement("div");
            formGroup.setAttribute("class", "form-group");
            formGroup.innerHTML = document.getElementById("principal").innerHTML;
            secao.appendChild(formGroup);
            document.getElementById("Corpo").appendChild(secao);
}
```

https://codepen.io/alvaro-alves/pen/zJzpMG?editors=1011

Comment: Deu certo!Muitissimo obrigado.

Comment: @CaioFrias Que bom que ajudou, marque como resposta por favor :D